# How to add external css and scss with bootstrap 4 in vue js 3 application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, sass

I need suggestion. I am using vue 3 rignt now. I want to convert my current web into vue application. I am using scss in my current file and I have main.css and main.scss folder.
The directory structures are below:

```
mian.css folder:
bootstrap.min.css
font.css
responsive.css
stye.css
main.scss folder:
_responsive.scss
style.scss
```

I am here very confused how to add scss and css globally along with boostrap4 in my vue app. Can anyone give me suggestions. I have checked lots of question stackoverflow but I did not able to get any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can store your css files within the src / assets folders. Then you can  import these files in the main.js file.

like below;

```
import "./assets/main.css"
```

Comment: thanks for yoru response. what about main,scss file? Is my main.scss file work if I only import import "./assets/main.css" ?

Comment: You don't need to import your scss file.  But you should install sass to vue. 

npm install -D sass-loader node-sass           For more detail => https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass

Comment: Yes its works that ways then why we need to add scss in vue.config.js file?